# How to get a piece of a stretched image?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a picture box that has a stretched image in it. I have a selection rectangle on a portion of the image. I am trying to save the selection as a new image. It is not taking into account the stretch of the main picture box, so it is not capturing the correct selection rectangle coordinates.  Here is my code snippet (when this is called, selection rectangle is already set):

```
Dim sourcebmp As New Bitmap(picScan.Image)
Dim destinationbmp As New Bitmap(selection.Width, selection.Height)
Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destinationbmp)
Dim destinationrectangle As New Rectangle(0, 0, selection.Width, selection.Height)
gr.DrawImage(sourcebmp, destinationrectangle, selection, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
picScan.Image = New Bitmap(destinationbmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a sample that solves the problem:

```
'Take a temporary snapshot of the picture box:
Dim tempBitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(picScan.ClientSize.Width, picScan.ClientSize.Height)
picScan.DrawToBitmap(tempBitmap, picScan.ClientRectangle)

'Copy the selection rectangle from the temporary snapshot to the target bitmap:
Dim target As New Bitmap(selection.Width, selection.Height)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(target)
   g.DrawImage(tempBitmap, target.GetBounds(0), selection, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
End Using

tempBitmap.Dispose()
picScan.Image = target
```